# Где ставится запятая, до и или после И?

Tags: запятые, сложное-предложение

Где ставится запятая в этом предложении?

> Тихо произнес я и как только тяжелая дверь отворилась, прошмыгнул внутрь.

Comment: Hanu, на сайте принято благодарить участников за все полезные вопросы и ответы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх, а также принимать один из ответов галочкой как наиболее понравившийся и решивший проблему.

Answer (score 1):

**Тихо произнес я и, как только тяжелая дверь отворилась, прошмыгнул внутрь.**

Запятая в вашем случае должна быть после 'и'. 'И' соединяет два однородных сказуемых: *'произнёс'* и *'прошмыгнул'*, а не относится к части, выделенной запятыми.